# Vuetify - Drop down menu doesn't highlight on mouse over

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I've created a drop down menu in **Vuetify** but whilst it works, it doesn't highlight each option as I move my mouse across them. I've got a snip of the screen to show what I mean..

the mouse pointer is missing from it but is hovering over My Settings.

My html and script code are below.  What have I missed please?

[image]

```
 <v-menu
  v-model="actions"
 >
   <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
     <v-btn
       icon
       v-on="on"
     >
       <v-icon>mdi-arrow-down-drop-circle</v-icon>
     </v-btn>
   </template>

   <v-list>
     <v-list-item
       v-for="(item, i) in items"
       :key="i"
       @click="stuff"
     >
       <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
     </v-list-item>
   </v-list>
 </v-menu>
```

then my script contains this data

```
items: [
    { title: 'My Preferences' },
    { title: 'My Settings' },
    { title: 'Log out' },
  ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boussadjra has a good workaround but the real problem here is that `@click="stuff"` is probably not a valid method. That's why your list is not highlighting. I've tested your code in a codepen changing the click listener to `@click=""` or `@click="thisIsAValidMethod()"` (I added the methods in methods in the `scripts` section) and it worked right away.

Vuetify uses many examples where you can use `v-menu` with `v-list` fyi - so you don't necessarily need to use `v-select`

Comment: Thank you Cathy - I'm not sure what Boussadjra meant as a drop down is not the same as a menu..  I have accepted your answer as I changed stuff to stuff() and it worked.  Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who stumbles upon this:
In my case I did not have any specific style when hovering v-menu options.
It happened because my @click="method()" was on the v-list-item-title in stead of v-list-item

Answer (score 0):

I see that you could achieve the same use case using `v-select` component in which each item will be highlighted when you move the mouse across it :

```
 <v-select
            v-model="selectedItems"
            :items="items"
            menu-props="auto"
            label="Select"
            hide-details

            single-line
          ></v-select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add the `link` attribute to the `v-list-item`.